# Using the --glob_ignores flag of SVN_Load_Dirs.PL

Tags: perl, svn

I am attempting to use the SVN_Load_Dirs.PL script file (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_load_dirs/) to attempt to merge a platform drop.

However, I can't get the --glob_ignores flag to behave as I'd expect, and I know so little perl that I can't dig into the script to understand why. The format I am using is: 
--glob_ignores=*.jazzignore

Where I want to ignore all .jazzignore files (although I am fine with anything with "jazzignore" in either the extension or name being ignored. I've looked for examples but can't find any actual usage of this flag anywhere. What I am looking for is a way to ignore all .jazzignore files and a few entire directories (like jazz5 for an example)

I assumed the flag would then be --glob_ignores="*.jazzignore *.jazz5" but that doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Try wrapping the value in quotes. It's likely your shell is expanding the `*` character. ie: `--glob_ignores='*.jazzignore'`

Comment: That's what I assumed, so I already had attempted that. It doesn't appear to be the issue.

Comment: Can you give us more information on what you mean by "... to behave as I'd expect...".  I would expect it to successfully ignore files with extension ".jazzignore" but __fail to ignore directories called "jazz5"__ (ie no extension on the directory name).  Is that what its doing?  If not, can you say anything about partial behaviour etc??

Comment: That is what I would expect as well. The current behavior is not ignoring jazzignore folders or files with the flag "--glob_ignores=*.jazzignore" regardless of whether there are quotes around .jazzignore or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the script was failing silently because I was running it from a windows cmd (and therefore never getting to the flag option). Apparently there are some issues running it this way and it was designed to be run from a linux command line. After switching it works perfectly.